# Find the expectation and variance fo the given function PDF

Tags: probability

Let X be a continuous random varible with PDF

$
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    \frac{1}{x+1}, & x\in (1,4)  \\
    0, & x\notin (1,4) \\
   \end{cases}
$

$a)$ Find $E(X)$

$b)$ Find $V(X)$

$c)$ determine the value of the variable X, for which E (X) is not defined

My attemp is:

$a)$ I now the fact $$ E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x)dx$$

From here we have:
$$ E(X)=\int_{1}^{4}x\frac{1}{x+1}dx=\int_{1}^{4}\frac{x+1-1}{x+1}dx=\int_{1}^{4} (1-\frac{1}{x+1})\ dx=x|_1^4-\ln(x+1)|_1^4=\ln\frac{2e^3}{5}$$

Now find $E(X^2)=?$

$$ E(X^2)=\int_{1}^{4}x^2\frac{1}{x+1}dx=\int_{1}^{4}\frac{x^2-1+1}{x+1}dx=\int_{1}^{4} (x-1+\frac{1}{x+1})\ dx=\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}|_1^4-\ln(x+1)|_1^4=\ln\frac{5e^4\sqrt e}{2}$$

$b)$ $Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=1.01$

I'm not sure if I found the part a) and b) well, if they are good please let someone tell me they are ok, if they are not good, please help me how to find

but do not know how to assign the part $c)$

Thanks for your atteniton and your help

Comment: That PDF is not normalized.

Comment: what do you mean by that please

Comment: The integral of the PDF should equal 1.

Comment: I know this, but that is the example of the book, can you help me sir

Comment: can someone help me, or can we conclude that the task is not well given in the book

Comment: Parts (a) and (b) look correct from what you are given.  To be normalized, the PDF should be divided by $\ln(5/2)$.

Comment: with `to be normalized` understand the axiom of normalization with certainty, ie that the integral is equal to 1, or not, if parts a) and b) are are correct, what can you tell me about part c) please

Comment: Part (c) makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: it is true that no X is presented to any seller so that it can then be assigned